# Unable to upload the objects into AWS S3 bucket using NodeJS...getting Access Denied 403

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm getting following error while trying to upload the objects into AWS S3 using a NodeJS program.

```
2020-07-24T15:04:45.744Z    91aaad14-c00a-12c4-89f6-4c59fee047a1    INFO    uploading to S3
2020-07-24T15:04:47.383Z    91aaad14-c00a-12c4-89f6-4c59fee047a1    INFO    Bucket has been created already
2020-07-24T15:04:47.714Z    91aaad14-c00a-12c4-89f6-4c59fee047a1    INFO    AccessDenied: Access Denied
    at Request.extractError (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:831:35)
    at Request.callListeners (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)
    at Request.transition (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /opt/nodejs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:690:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18) {
  code: 'AccessDenied',
  region: null,
  time: 2020-07-24T15:04:47.713Z,
  requestId: '3FB484FAC50110BF',
```

Here is my S3 bucket creation and upload code (connect.ts) in NodeJS:-

```
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';
export class S3Client {
protected client: AWS.S3

constructor(accessKeyId: string, secretAccessKey: string) {
    this.client = new AWS.S3( { accessKeyId, secretAccessKey } )
}

public uploadToS3(bucketName: string, folderName: string, subFolderName: string,
    anotherSubFolderName: string, region: string, FILE_NAME: string, contents: any) {
            console.log('uploading to S3');
            let params: AWS.S3.Types.PutObjectRequest = {
                        Bucket: bucketName,
                        Key: `${folderName}/${subFolderName}/${anotherSubFolderName}/${FILE_NAME}`,
                        Body: contents,
                        ContentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        ACL: 'public-read',
                        CacheControl: 'max-age=60'
            }

            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.client.createBucket({Bucket: bucketName}, (error, data) => {
                        if (error && error.statusCode == 409){
            console.log("Bucket has been created already");
          }else{
                            console.log('Bucket Created Successfully');
                        } 
                        this.client.putObject(params, (error, data) => {
                            if (error) {
                                return reject(error);
                            }
                            console.log("Successfully uploaded data to " + bucketName);
                            return resolve(data);
                        });
        })
            })

    }; 

}
```

I'm writing a Lambda function using SAM (Serverless Application Model) template. I have created an IAM user with CLI credentials (access/secret access keys) with full access to S3 bucket. My Lambda function works well but when I try to upload the object then it gets failed with this access denied error. I have added console.log() to see if I'm able to read the access/secret access keys from environment variables while trying to create the S3 client object like below :-

**index.ts:-**

```
import { S3Client } from './s3/connect';
const s3Client = new S3Client(
    process.env.ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    process.env.SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
)

const res = await s3Client.uploadToS3(bucketName, folderName, subFolderName,
                    anotherSubFolderName, region, FILE_NAME, JSON.stringify({ hello: 'world' }));
```

Please assist to advise on my following queries:-

1. How to make sure that I'm using the right AWS account or not? Because although it says, bucket has been already been created but I do not see any bucket when I log on to the AWS console. As buckets are globally, so I do not see any bucket from the given list. So, not sure if bucket got created in the right AWS account or not.
2. If everything is correct then can you please advise when it should I check further to debug this access denied issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the region through to your function, but you aren't actually setting it in your PutObjectRequest or when you create your s3client..

ie, a generic s3 object:

```
const credentials = { accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY, secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_S3_SECRET }
const s3 = new AWS.S3({ region: 'eu-west-1', credentials, useArnRegion: true })
```

edit.. I think that buckets default to us-west-1 so maybe look in s3 for that region on your account?